# PHP running from Apache cannot write to filesystem

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services

I cannot make PHP write a file to filesystem when running from Apache webserver.

I have a simple PHP script:

```
<?php
print 'User : '.posix_getpwuid(posix_getuid())['name'];
print ' ';
print 'Group: '.posix_getgrgid(posix_getgid())['name'];
file_put_contents('./test.txt', 'OK');
?>
```

I'm logged in as user `ec2-user:ec2-user` and just for testing Apache is running as `ec2-user:ec2-user`.

`ec2-user` belongs to the following groups:

```
>groups
ec2-user adm wheel systemd-journal www
```

The script is located in Apache document root.

```
/var/www/html/test.php

drwxr-xr-x.  21 root root 4096 ene 31 05:45 var
drwxrwsr-x.  4 root www    31 ene 29 17:30 www
drwxrwsr-x. 2 root www 36 ene 31 06:16 html
-rw-rw-r--. 1 ec2-user www 172 ene 31 06:15 test.php
```

If a run the script vis PHP cli the file `test.txt` is created and the following output is generated.

```
>php ./test.php
User : ec2-user Group: ec2-user
```

But if I call the script via my browser as a normal web page or via curl, I get a file permissions error:

```
> curl http://my.ip/test.php
User : ec2-user Group: ec2-user<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  file_put_contents(./test.txt): failed to open stream:     Permission denied in <b>/var/www/html/test.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
```

I have tried also to run Apache as `ec2-user:www`, but the output is the same:

```
User : ec2-user Group: www
Warning: file_put_contents(./test.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/test.php on line 6
```

I have checked PHP configuration and there is no `open_basedir` option configured.

I have tried to write to a `/dummy` folder with `777` permissions and the same output.

Is there any configuration I'm missing?

Comment: I have no solution but you are on AWS I am assuming, so don't forget to add `aws` tag in your question. Its somehow related to that.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/293143/php-fopen-always-fails-with-permission-denied

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check selinux is enabled

```
selinuxenabled && echo enabled || echo disabled
```

if it is enabled, try to disable

```
echo 0 > /selinux/enforce
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks. You can also check SeLinux status with `getenforce`. I disabled it editing `SELINUX=disabled` in `/etc/selinux/config`and rebooting. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Enabling_and_Disabling_SELinux-Disabling_SELinux.html